# Use php to read static html page, add meta tags, then load modified page

Tags: php, facebook, meta-tags

I am trying to use PHP to inject meta tags into an existing html file that contains several javascript commands.  The overall issue I am trying to solve is to get the open graph meta tags for Facebook into the file that gets called on the application that is written in javascript.

Using PHP, I have tried reading in the index.html file, find the  tag, insert the meta tags, and then echo the modified file.  Problem is that the modified file always ends up showing the head tag as follows, skipping the tags I added in by putting them further down the file.

```
<head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>
```

The one javascript index.html file gets reused for several different pages, so I can't just put the completed tags in it since they could be different every time.

How can I inject the 6 different meta og and one fb tags after the `<head>` tag?

Comment: Did you try an HTML/XML parser? Seems like the perfect tool for the job.

Comment: Just tried an HTML parser.  Thought I had it until I ran it through Facebook's Object Debugger. That still shows the line: <head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>

and now the section of html that I changed shows as: &lt;head&gt;
&lt;meta http-equiv="Content-Type"

So there are now two head sections, with one using the actual <> characters and the other using HTML Entities.

This is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 1):

In your php file, specify a variable. could be anything, as an example:

```
$var=$randomarray[0][pagetitle];
```

insert it into the head output

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo"$var";?>" />
```

Comment: I have tried searching for the <head> characters, and I have tried inserting a marker comment to search for and replace, but PHP keeps changing the text read from the original index.html file that I need to inject the meta tags into. This is from a photographer gallery software package that has been around for several years and was written in javascript.

Comment: oh your script is running through constantly updating static html pages.  You need to find the file that is writing the html pages, and alter the values there, which will in turn update the html file properly everytime it is changed.

Comment: No, index.html is a 100% static page, but depending on URL line variables different Javascript actions happen. Index.html is generated in JAlbum  or Phoyoshop. I need to add meta tags dynamicly depending on which of the hundreds image pages in a gallery the Facebook like button is clicked. Everything starts with the static index.html file. So this time I need this set of tags, next time need different ones.

Answer (score 0):

if your php file contains a body tag then it is easy just do:

```
$file = file_get_contents('index.html');    
$str = '<meta /></head>';    
$file = str_replace('</head>', $str, $file );
echo $file;
```

just replace $str with your expected html, be sure to add "`</head>`" at the end.

Comment: Not starting with a PHP file, but rather an existing index.html file.  I have tried file_get_contents('index.html') and then search for <head>, insert meta tags, and echo file, but the result ends up with the <head> line I mentioned above, and my meta tags are 3 or so lines past the </head> line in the file.  Even just reading and echoing the file changes the <head> structure from the original html file.

Comment: dont search for <head>, search for <body> tag, and i will update my answer to suite your scenario.

Comment: The index.html does contain a <body> tag, but no <meta /> tag.  The <body> tag is considerably after the </head> tag, so that would end up putting the the meta tags outside of the <head></head> section, making them not to function properly. I thought it should be this simple, but it is not. I thought I should be ablr to search for the <head> tag and replace it with <head>{extra text}.

Comment: oh i did not think about that basically you have to just search for </head> tag